# Why process blocked forever when call sleep in Celluloid::IO

Tags: ruby, celluloid

I'm using `Celluloid::IO` to do DNS query and below is my code:

```
require 'celluloid/io'

class MyResolver
    include Celluloid::IO

    def initialize
        @resolver = DNSResolver.new
    end 

    def resolve(domain)
        ips = @resolver.resolve domain

        #sleep 1
        return {domain: domain, ip: ips}
    end 
end

pool = MyResolver.pool(size: 5)

domains = [ 
    'www.google.com',
    ## many other record
]

futures = domains.map {|d| pool.future.resolve(d)}

futures.each do |future|
    puts "#{future.value}"
end
```

This code works and finished in few seconds. But when I add the line `sleep 1`(just for learning purpose), after printing some results, the process blocked forever, which is very strange.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sleep` is an overridden keyword in `Celluloid`, so if you want `sleep` from `Ruby` itself, use `Kernel.sleep`. But that being said, as of `0.17.0-dependent` branch of `Celluoid::IO` this error you describe does not exist ( anymore? ).

I used your reproducible failing case to test the new `celluloid-pool` gem being released in version `0.17.0` of `Celluloid`, and it is working no problem *with* `sleep 1` as is.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with DNSResolver at least in that case, but you can use "thread-aware DNS resolver" [Resolv](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/resolv/rdoc/Resolv.html) from standard ruby library - no any blocks with ~25k domains array. Don't forget to catch exceptions from Resolv.

Comment: **DNSResolver** in `celluloid::io` is using 'resolv'. the code is [here](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid-io/blob/master/lib/celluloid/io/dns_resolver.rb)

Comment: I see but just tried to call `Resolv.getaddress domain` in `resolve(domain)` instead of init and use `@resolver` instance - problem is gone.